# What is Debug Channel?

Tags: debugging, channel

Our professor asked us to write a debug channel in c++. But I don't know what a debug channel is. He just told us to use our critical thinking mind to figure this out.
So if you know, please tell me where I can find the concept of channel in software development. I want details and how to write a debug channel in c++.

Comment: I think he was referring to a "channel" in a general way; maybe he just wants you to add some hidden debug functionality - e.g. a small shell to check the internal state of the program. But to give you a meaningful answer you should give some more context.

Comment: What's the point of a critical thinking exercise if you're going to get someone else to do your thinking for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, googling your question before posting it here is recommended. I've found a potential resource for you here:

**http://libcwd.sourceforge.net/reference-manual/group__group__debug__channels.html**
And here:
**http://libcwd.sourceforge.net/tutorial/tut2.html**

I'm not a C++ specialist but those seem to be the answer you're looking for.